# Why is my meta.programmers reputation the same as my programmers rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I just noticed that my rep on Meta Programmers is the same (currently 3898) as it is on Programmers. This is surely a bug, unless there's been a recent change to combine rep on meta sites with the main sites.

Comment: **[canonical answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64268/165773)** to this question was given by SE Community Manager at MSO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could've sworn we've fielded this question before, but at any rate, this is not a bug: every child meta except for Meta Stack Overflow pegs its users' reputation to the corresponding main site user. It's been like that since Stack Exchange 2.0 launched.

From [the Meta FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

Comment: Thanks for that -- I didn't realize SE sites were different from SO in this respect, but I should've thought to check the FAQ.

Comment: (ok : i was typing the same question)..so better ask here the link gives [error-reputation click](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/users/42987/presleydias?tab=reputation)

Comment: may be the link should say that `your reputation activity is non existent` as i dnt have any activity on Meta